# Upload site FTP via VPN

Tags: ftp, vpn

I'm finishing a website for a client. The site was made in Webflow, and I have to export the code to be uploaded to the client server. The site is in HTML / CSS. 
I'm a graphic designer and I've only recently started working on web projects. 
The client sent me the following information to upload the site:

[Client Info Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/971qJ.jpg)

In addition, the client added this information:

FTP access only works over the VPN so you need to establish the VPN connection before FTP.

Is there anyone around here who can help me? I really do not know what to do with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a VPN client, just search for one that is trustfull and download it (I normally use the SonicWall Global VPN Client).

Once you donwloaded it, you will stabilish connection with the VPN the client sent to you using all the required information.

After that, just go to the File Explorer and enter the URL this way: `ftp://[address sent by the client]`. It will ask you for the credentials, then you will be connected.

Once you're there, just drop the files on the appropriate folder and test on the URL that the client sent to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try that :)

Comment: Olá Claúdio!
Só hoje voltei a esse projeto. Estou tentando fazer o que me disse, mas tenho realmente pouca experiência nessa área. Seria possível me dar uma ajuda?
Eu fiz download do SonicWall, mas não consigo avançar desse ponto.
Quando inicio o software, ele me pede o IP Address or Domain Name e tambem um Connection Name. Na verdade não sei que dados que me foram fornecidos devo introduzir aqui. Também não sei o que fazer a seguir a esse passo.
Muito Obrigado

Comment: In this section of stack overflow, we need to type only in english. Seeing the image that you posted, there's a "Host" under the "Access VPN". You could try it as the IP/Domain. This will create the VPN for you. After that, you have to connect to it. Just click on the green play button "Enable" and enter the user/password. There is the pre-shared key. Just type it once you're asked for it